# How can I paint a number of animated bubbles ? (Qt4.6)

Tags: qt, qt4.6

Recently in trouble, I hope you will help me .
I created three buttons in a widget ,I use the QPropertyAnimation class to achieve the position of the three buttons move .

such as this example:

```
QPushButton button("Animated Button");
 button.show();

 QPropertyAnimation animation(&button, "geometry");
 animation.setDuration(10000);

 animation.setKeyValueAt(0, QRect(0, 0, 100, 30));
 animation.setKeyValueAt(0.8, QRect(250, 250, 100, 30));
 animation.setKeyValueAt(1, QRect(0, 0, 100, 30));

 animation.start();
```

I want to paint  a number of animated bubbles around these buttons when they are moving. There is no OpenGL and qml .    Paint bubbles in paintEvent() or any other good idea ?
I am concerned about the running speed and effect in ARM 9 board ...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no better solution. I can also write a more animation.